# Jenkins fails with Uncaught Exception: *** -[_NSStdIOFileHandle writeData:]: Broken pipe

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, continuous-integration, fastlane

I am trying to do CICD setup with Jenkins for my iOS Project(**Xcode 10.2.1**).
I am using Fastlane to create lanes for testing, archiving etc.

All the lanes are working perfectly except Test lane. If i execute the lanes using terminal directly, there is no issue recorded. It works just fine. Please find the test lane below

```
desc "run tests"
lane :executetest do
begin
            # Something where you'd like to be able to react to failures
  scan(scheme: "iOSProjectTests")

            # If ANY exception happens, let me handle it
            rescue => ex
            # re-raise the exception unless it's something we're OK with ignoring
            # raise ex unless ex.message.include?('Error message of interest')
            # UI.error ex
            # UI.user_error!("Lint check or Test case failed, but continuing anyway!")
        UI.important("There were a few failing test cases. Continuing execution")

        end
end
```

But in jenkins, as soon as the test lane starts i am getting below exception and the build fails,

```
** INTERNAL ERROR: Uncaught exception while building **
[18:09:51]: ▸ Uncaught Exception: *** -[_NSStdIOFileHandle writeData:]: Broken pipe
[18:09:51]: ▸ Stack:
[18:09:52]: ▸ 0   __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
[18:09:52]: ▸ 1   objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
[18:09:52]: ▸ 2   +[NSException raise:format:] (in CoreFoundation)
[18:09:52]: ▸ 3   -[NSConcreteFileHandle writeData:] (in Foundation)
[18:09:52]: ▸ 4   IDETestingFileHandleOutputStream.write(_:) (in IDEFoundation)
[18:09:52]: ▸ 5   @objc IDETestingFileHandleOutputStream.write(_:) (in IDEFoundation)
[18:09:52]: ▸ 6   specialized IDETestingMultiOutputStream.write(_:) (in IDEFoundation)
[18:09:52]: ▸ 7   @objc IDETestingFileHandleOutputStream.write(_:) (in IDEFoundation)
[18:09:52]: ▸ 8   specialized IDETestingLaunchSession.parseConsoleOutput(fromOriginalOutput:) (in IDEFoundation)
[18:09:52]: ▸ 9   @objc IDETestingLaunchSession.parseConsoleOutput(fromOriginalOutput:) (in IDEFoundation)
[18:09:52]: ▸ 10   -[IDEConsoleAdaptor _delegateProcessedOutput:] (in IDEFoundation)
[18:09:52]: ▸ 11   -[IDEConsoleAdaptor _getData:fileHandle:overflowBuffer:stringBuffer:] (in IDEFoundation)
[18:09:52]: ▸ 12   -[IDEConsoleAdaptor _getDataFromNotification:overflowBuffer:stringBuffer:] (in IDEFoundation)
[18:09:52]: ▸ 13   -[IDEConsoleAdaptor _getOutputFromNotification:] (in IDEFoundation)
[18:09:52]: ▸ 14   DVTInvokeWithLazyFailureHint (in DVTFoundation)
[18:09:52]: ▸ 15   -[_DVTNotificationReceiver receiveNotification:] (in DVTFoundation)
[18:09:52]: ▸ 16   __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ (in CoreFoundation)
[18:09:52]: ▸ 17   ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke (in CoreFoundation)
[18:09:52]: ▸ 18   _CFXRegistrationPost (in CoreFoundation)
[18:09:52]: ▸ 19   ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke (in CoreFoundation)
[18:09:52]: ▸ 20   -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] (in CoreFoundation)
[18:09:52]: ▸ 21   _CFXNotificationPost (in CoreFoundation)
[18:09:52]: ▸ 22   -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] (in Foundation)
[18:09:52]: ▸ 23   -[IDEMasterPtyFileHandle _gotData:] (in IDEFoundation)
[18:09:52]: ▸ 24   __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ (in CoreFoundation)
[18:09:52]: ▸ 25   ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke (in CoreFoundation)
[18:09:52]: ▸ 26   _CFXRegistrationPost (in CoreFoundation)
[18:09:52]: ▸ 27   ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke (in CoreFoundation)
[18:09:52]: ▸ 28   -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] (in CoreFoundation)
[18:09:52]: ▸ 29   _CFXNotificationPost (in CoreFoundation)
[18:09:52]: ▸ 30   -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] (in Foundation)
[18:09:52]: ▸ 31   _performFileHandleSource (in Foundation)
[18:09:52]: ▸ 32   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ (in CoreFoundation)
[18:09:52]: ▸ 33   __CFRunLoopDoSource0 (in CoreFoundation)
[18:09:52]: ▸ 34   __CFRunLoopDoSources0 (in CoreFoundation)
[18:09:52]: ▸ 35   __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
[18:09:52]: ▸ 36   CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
[18:09:52]: ▸ 37   CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
[18:09:52]: ▸ 38   -[Xcode3CommandLineBuildTool _buildWithTimingSection:] (in Xcode3Core)
[18:09:52]: ▸ 39   -[Xcode3CommandLineBuildTool run] (in Xcode3Core)
[18:09:52]: ▸ 40   main (in xcodebuild)
[18:09:52]: ▸ 41   start (in libdyld.dylib)
```

Couldn't get any help regarding this anywhere. There are only default XCTest cases written in the project. It is not even a real test case.

Comment: I am also facing same problem in xcode 10.2, is it working for you now?

Comment: @Ashok Please refer to my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the fastlane to below

```
desc "run tests"
lane :executetest do
begin
            # Something where you'd like to be able to react to failures

   scan(
    scheme: "iOSProjectTests",
    devices: ["iPhone X"],
    output_style: "standard")
            # If ANY exception happens, let me handle it
            rescue => ex
            # re-raise the exception unless it's something we're OK with ignoring
            # raise ex unless ex.message.include?('Error message of interest')
            # UI.error ex
            # UI.user_error!("Lint check or Test case failed, but continuing anyway!")
        UI.important("There were a few failing test cases. Continuing execution")

        end
end
```

And I was using Homebrew to run the jenkins. Instead used `Jenkins-lts` to start the jenkins. This fixed the above issue.